JS7 Jobscheduler spooler_process_after and spooler_process_result
I am completely new to JS7 Jobscheduler (https://www.sos-berlin.com/en/jobscheduler-features). Does anyone know how can I convert the javascript below to shell script in Jobscheduler? The aim is to have a script that is compatible with both JS1 and JS7 Jobscheduler. I have tried to find any information from the documentation e.g. https://kb.sos-berlin.com/display/PKB/Monitors and related topics but could not find any reference to shell script. Thank you in advanced.
function spooler_process_after(spooler_process_result) {
    if(!spooler_process_result){
        spooler_task.order.setback();
        return false;
    }
}

